# How do I verify an xPath expression in Selenium IDE?

Tags: xpath, selenium-ide

How would I test for the following expression in Selenium?

```
not(//select[@id='ddlCountry']/@class) or
not(contains(//select[@id='ddlCountry']/@class,'invalidValue'))
```

true if the class attribute doesnt exist, or if it does, the attribute doesn't contain `invalidValue`.

I've tried using the `verifyElementPresent` command, but it errors out, I assume because I'm returning a boolean rather than a node.

I'm happy with an alternative to this if theres no way to do the above using xPath.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for an easy solution. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case your XPath engine API doesnt allow expressions returning atomic values (not nodes), then you still can

**Use**:

```
//select[@id='ddlCountry'][contains(@class,'invalidValue')]
```

and test if an element was selected or not.

Comment: spot on. thanks. a much better xPath expression than my own as well.

Answer (score 0):

> true if the class attribute doesnt
>   exist, or if it does, the attribute
>   doesn't contain `invalidValue`.

```
not(//select[@id='ddlCountry']/@class[contains(.,'invalidValue')])
```

Comment: this still fails if i run it through as a test, either fails the 'false' test case(no attribute), or the true test case (has an attribute) depending the check (verifyElementPresent/verifyElementNotPresent), but it doesnt pass both checks.

Comment: @jasper: I didn't catch that you need to select a node rather than return a boolean value. Deleting answer.